# How to add a virtual adapter to pool bandwidth from different adapters

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, windows-8

How do you create a virtual adapter other than the Loopback adapter in Windows (8, 64 bit ) that can connect to the physical network and obtain/use(dynamic/static) IP?

I would like to use multiple IP addresses on my machine and pool the bandwidth on all adapters using Connectify Dispatch

Is that possible ?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, Dispatch should handle the virtual adapter automatically.

In other scenarios, "teaming", or "link aggregation" is a feature of some enterprise/server level hardware and drivers for combining the bandwidth of multiple interfaces connected to the same network.

Comment: Do you mean to say that Dispatch will create a virtual adapter for me? From what i know, i don't think that is possible. It can utilize only when the adapter is created. 

I understand that servers are capable of adding more than one physical Ethernet cards. But, is there a way to emulate such capability in Windows?

Comment: I'm really not understanding your question...
Dispatch takes more than one physical adapter (Ethernet, WiFi, LTE, whatever) and creates a virtual (software) adapter that appears to have the summed bandwidth.

Comment: Correct. I wanted to know if there is a way to obtain more than one IP address on a LAN using one NIC. If yes, can we pool the internet bandwidth on those 2 IP addresses?

Comment: No. IP addresses don't have bandwidth, the NIC itself does.
You can add two IPs to one NIC, but they share the bandwidth.

Comment: Adding IP addresses like you said is one way. Is there a way to achieve that using virtual adapters? There would be 2 adapters (1 virtual + 1 real) in that case as against a single real adapter.

Comment: Again, no. To do what you want you need multiple physical adapters. No way around that.